# Add an ant target to run a class from within a jar file

Tags: java, ant

I have a jar file with multiple executable classes, how can I run the main method of a using an ant target ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at the [Ant Java Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html). You should be able to create a target that looks like this:

```
<target name="mytarget" description="runs my class" >
  <java classname="test.Main">
    <classpath>
      <pathelement location="dist/test.jar"/>
    </classpath>
  </java>
</target>
```

Alternative, using [Ant Exec Task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html):

```
<target name="mytarget" description="runs my class">
     <exec executable="java">
       <arg line="-classpath dist/test.jar test.Main"/>
     </exec>
</target>
```

Answer (score 3):

Using ant's java task:

```
<java fork="yes" classname="com.example.Class" failonerror="true">
  <classpath>
    <pathelement path="path/to/jar/containing/the/com.example.Class"/>
    ...
  </classpath>
  ...
</java>
```

Answer (score 2):

First you have to decide which class is used as entry point.

Let's assume that the class is `com.mycompany.Main`

in this case if you wish to run application from command line say

```
java -cp my.jar com.mycompany.Main
```

Now you can either run it as java program:

```
   <java classname="com.mycompany.Main">
     <classpath>
       <pathelement location="myjar.jar"/>
     </classpath>
   </java>
```

(see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html)

or run it as an generic external process:

(see http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/exec.html).

I think that using java target is preferable.